# Is there any asymmetric file encryption software which is PKCS #11 compatible (like PGP) under Windows?

Tags: windows, encryption

I'm looking for a asymmetric file encryption software (e.g. with RSA algorithm) like PGP (but under Windows). I need the software to be PKCS #11 compatible to let me choose arbitrary security tokens with it. Does anybody know a software with the specified features? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please be aware that PGP uses hybrid encryption - the symmetric key is encrypted with the asymmetric private one.